# What is the difference between low threshold parameter and high threshold parameter in cv2.Canny?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to apply Canny function to the image to detect the edges.

This is how the function looks like:

```
cv2.Canny(image, threshold1, threshold2, apertureSize, L2gradient)
```

> threshold1: It is the High threshold value of intensity gradient.

> threshold2: It is the Low threshold value of intensity gradient.

I do not understand the difference between threshold1 and threshold2. I searched it online but I am still not able to understand it.

Here is my original image:
[image]

An example with low threshold1 and high threshold2:

```
canny_low_threshold1 = cv2.Canny(blurred_image, 10, 100)
cv2.imshow("low_threshold1", canny_low_threshold)
```

[image]
Here is the exact opposite:

```
canny_high_threshold1 = cv2.Canny(blurred_image, 100, 10 )
cv2.imshow("high_threshold1", canny_high_threshold1)
```

[image]

They produce exactly the same output. Could somebody please explain me the difference?

Comment: They're not really "High threshold" and "Low threshold". The minimum of the two thresholds is used as the minVal and the maximum is used for maxVal. By switching the values without changing them, you're making no change to the values used or the output produced. See the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html), especially section 5, and the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de).

Answer (score 0):

For example,
We have points A,B, C .If point A is higher than the maxVAl it is considered as an edge, if B is inbetween maxVal and minVal, and the point B is not connected to the pointA which is above the maxVal it is not observed as an edge. If point C is below minVal it is not considered as an edge at all.
The maxVal and minVal tend to separate potential edges from false edges